# How to pass a message's attributes when using gcloud sdk call cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

From this https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/call

I can pass a message data to the background cloud function.

And, I can pass a message attributes using `cloud Pub/Sub` like this:

```js
this.pubsubClient
      .topic(topic)
      .publisher()
      .publish(message, attributes);
```

But, how to pass a message attributes to the background cloud function using `gcloud beta functions call` command?

There is no `--attributes` argument for it.

Comment: Have you tried following the documentation?  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/direct#cloud_pubsub_example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gcloud functions call](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/call) has a `--data` flag, which accepts a `JSON` string:

```
--data '{"message": "Hello World!", "attributes": "0655"}'
```